# keep upstart job running?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, upstart

When i run below UpStart job, UpStart job automatically stop when script ends. Is there any way to keep it running until i run initctl stop testjob. Like we use RemainAfterExit=yes in Systemd and it keeps service running until we stop it.

description "Test Job" 
author "Test Author" 
start on runlevel [2345]

exec /test/script.sh

Answer (score 0):

Use `pre-start exec /test/script.sh` rather than just `exec`.